# Creating a very simple upstart script

Tags: bash, upstart

So I've been attempting to create an incredibly simple upstart script.

I started with:

```
console output

exec /srv/scripts/test.sh
```

But got this error:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

So I changed it to:

```
console output

script
   set -x
   echo "Hello world!"
end script
```

This seems to run just find and dandy, but I don't get any output anywhere, and I was told there would be something written to `/var/log/upstart/test.log` (my script is `test.conf`). There was nothing written to that log file- in fact, that log file doesn't actually exist.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get just a simple script to run?

Comment: Where did you save the upstart job?

Comment: @Braiam In the `/etc/init` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Upstart is in error when it says you can use `console` and `exec`:

- `console` does not work at all, and
- `exec` only works if it's inside
  a `script` stanza.

Changing what I had to:

```
script
    exec /srv/scripts/test.sh
end script
```

worked, and it logged output in the log file. Unfortunately, I still have no idea how to log output to the console.